# SML/NJ searching in list of tuples of list

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am very new to SML/NJ and I am kind of lost. I have been trying to implement a function that is going to search through the list of tuples that have some lists in it, for example:

```
val x = [(5, 2, [9 , 8, 7]), (3, 4, [6, 5, 0]), (11, 12, [8, 3, 1])]
```

I would like my function to add the first element of the tuple to the new list once there is a match between my target number and a number in element 3 of the tuple. I have tried several implementations, but none of them work properly so far.

```
type id = int* int* int list;
val b:id list = [(5,2,[9,8,7]), (3,4,[6,5,0]), (11, 12, [8,3,1])]
val number: int = 8;
val a: int list = nil;

fun findNum(nil) = a | findNum (x: id list) =
    let val tem = hd(x)
        val theList = #3tem
        val i = #1tem
        fun findMatch(nil) = a | findMatch(tem) =
            if (number = hd(theList)) then i::a 
            else findMatch (tl(theList))
    in findNum(tl(x))
    end;

 findNum(b);
```

I know it is badly written, and that is why it keeps returning an empty list. I feel like I need to do "if else" instead of let/in/end so it will recursively call the rest of the tuples in the list. My problem is that I am not sure how to do it because if I use if/else then I cannot declare some value inside the function. I appreciate any suggestions or hints.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a simple example of input and desired output e.g for input `[(5,2,[9,8,7]), (3,4,[6,5,0]), (11, 12, [8,3,1])]` what output do you expect?

Comment: I expect it to return the list of first elements of tuples once the number in the third element are match. So it should be [5, 11 ] in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: What is "the new list"? Is that what you call the function's result value?

Comment: Yes, I meant the list of function's result value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might start with a function `member (x, xs)` that is true if `x` is an element in the list `xs`:

```
fun member (x, xs) = List.exists (fn y => x = y) xs
```

A base case is when the list of three-tuples is empty. Then `x` does not occur in the third element of any of the (non-existing) three-tuples, and the list of results is empty. A recursive case is achieved by pattern matching against the first element of the list being a three-tuple, `(i,j,xs)`, and the tail of the list, `ts`, and ask if `x` is a member of that third element `xs`; if it is, return the first part of the tuple, `i`:

```
fun find (x, []) = []
  | find (x, (i,j,xs)::ts) =
    if member (x, xs)
    then i :: find (x, ts)
    else find (x, ts)
```

A shorter version using the higher-order list combinators `map` and `filter`:

```
fun find (x, ts) = map #1 (filter (fn (i,j,xs) => member (x, xs)) ts)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation. This implementation is very short and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation with some slight changes:

```
type id = int* int* int list;
val b:id list = [(5,2,[9,8,7]), (3,4,[6,5,0]), (11, 12, [8,3,1])]
val number: int = 8;

fun findNum [] = [] 
  | findNum (x::xs)  =
        let 
           val theList :int list = #3 (x :id)
           val i : int = #1 x
           fun findMatch [] = false
             | findMatch (y::ys) = if (number = y) then true
                                   else findMatch ys
        in 
           if (findMatch theList = true) then i ::(findNum xs) 
           else (findNum xs) 
        end;
```

Example:

```
- findNum b;
val it = [5,11] : int list
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your if-then-elses can be shortened a bit. `if (number = y) then true else findMatch ys` is equivalent to `number = y orelse findMatch ys`. Similarly, `if (findMatch theList = true) then ...` can be shortened to `if findMatch theList then ...`.

Comment: @SimonShine, Thanks !!!, I wasn't so sure since I don't have  that experience in sml, thanks for the useful comment!!